# Query for historical data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a query in a postgresql database but I can't figure out how the way to make it. I have a historical table which stores the status of an object, the date and other data. Something like this:

```
id objectid    date    status    ....
----------------------------
9  12          date1   2
8  12          date2   2
7  12          date3   2    <-- This is the date where the last status was set
6  12          date4   1
5  12          date5   1
4  12          date6   6
3  12          date7   6
2  12          date8   2
1  12          date9   2
```

I need to get the date where the current status (the last one set for each object) has been set for all the objects in the system (objectid). So in the example (I have only included info for the object 12 to symplify) if they are ordered chronologically (date9 is the oldest and date1 is the earliest) the current status is 2 and I want to get date3 which is hen this status was set for the last time. Notice that status 2 was set earlier, but then it changed to 6, 1 and then to 2 again. I want to get the first date in the current interval.

Can anyone tell me how to construct this query or the way to go?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE** query accoring to @Unreason answer so it could be joined to the table which contains the object which objectid references to

```
SELECT objectid, max(date)
FROM (
    SELECT objectid, status, date, lag(status) OVER window1, last_value(status) OVER window1 last_status
    FROM historical
    WINDOW window1 AS ( PARTITION BY objectid ORDER BY date) 
    ) x 
WHERE (status <> lag OR lag IS NULL)
AND status = last_status
GROUP BY objectid
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, windowing functions come to mind

Something like

```
SELECT max(date)
FROM (
      SELECT status, date, lag(status) OVER window1, last_value(status) OVER window1 last_status
      FROM historical
      WHERE objectid = 12
      WINDOW window1 AS ( ORDER BY date) 
      ) x 
WHERE (status <> lag OR lag IS NULL)
      AND status = last_status;
```

Notes:

- using keywords as field names (such as lag and date) should be avoided
- there are many other ways to write this query
- currently it works for one object (`objectid = 12`), but it could be modified to return the date of last status for each object

**EDIT**
Test data

```
CREATE TABLE historical (
    id integer,
    objectid integer,
    date date,
    status integer
);

INSERT INTO historical VALUES (1, 12, '2000-01-01', 2);
INSERT INTO historical VALUES (2, 12, '2001-01-01', 2);
INSERT INTO historical VALUES (3, 12, '2002-01-01', 6);
INSERT INTO historical VALUES (4, 12, '2003-01-01', 6);
INSERT INTO historical VALUES (5, 12, '2004-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO historical VALUES (6, 12, '2005-01-01', 1);
INSERT INTO historical VALUES (7, 12, '2006-01-01', 2);
INSERT INTO historical VALUES (8, 12, '2007-01-01', 2);
INSERT INTO historical VALUES (9, 12, '2008-01-01', 2);
```

In future you might want to post results of your

```
pg_dump -t table_name --inserts
```

so it is easier to setup a test case

Comment: I didn't know windows functions. I think it's a good approach but I doesn't work. Now it returns 2006 which is ok, but if I add 'INSERT INTO historical VALUES (10, 12, '2009-01-01', 3);' it should return 2009 but it returns 2006 too.

Comment: Yup, made a mistake... switch the `first_value` with `last_value` (coincidentally the first_value according to date was 2 in test data, so it seemed to work)

Comment: Corrected the answer directly.

Comment: ok, now it works, though I need to use it to be joined on the table where I have the objects. I've tried it by myself and I think the query seems to work but I don't know why (I've edited my post and added it at the end of the post). In your query when you do WHERE objectid = 12 then it calculates last_value(status) only on that objectid which is ok. But in my query it also does the same (though I haven't gruped until the end), but how can the window know that it must calculate lag and last_value only when objectid is the same. Can you explain how window works and why my query works. Thanks.

Comment: I think I have to change "WINDOW window1 AS (ORDER BY date)" to  "WINDOW window1 AS (PARTITION BY objectid ORDER BY date)", is it ok?

Comment: yes, PARTITION will make the window functions reset their values... so putting that in subquery and also selecting the objectid will allow you to GROUP BY objectid in outer query and get all the dates of last status change by objectid

Answer (score 2):

```
select  min(date)
from    historical
where   status        =   2 
and     objectid      =   12
and     date > 
  (select max(date) 
    from  historical
    where status <> 2)
```

Comment: Using recursive query to get last status of objectid (or all objectids) would make the query equivalent and comparable to window approach, @Javi, if you have sizeable test data could you run some benchmarks and let us know which performs better? I would imagine window version should be faster...

Comment: @Unreason In a database of 350 rows both queries are similar in time (it doesn't always win the same). I don't have a bigger benchmark to try. Thank you @Neville K. as well.